# MySQL workbench, change format of auto generated queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

By default MySQL Workbench does things such as pre-pend the database name to table names as a prefix when it generates a query. It also wraps column names in the backticks `

For example if I delete a row and click Apply, it will display the query like this:

```
DELETE FROM `my_db`.`users` WHERE `user_id`='12345';
```

Is there a way to change settings of query generation to make it instead generate the query like this:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = '12345';
```

Comment: Interesting, I don't think it's possible but this is worthy of a feature request over at bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: Why? What do you care what it generates?

Comment: I use the queries it generates elsewhere, and would prefer a certain format.